# C# Regex on Array

Tags: c#, regex, webforms

I am currently writing a WebForms application, and I need to split an email address on the @ symbol and display the email address across two lines.

The problem I have is I cannot use a Regex.Split on an array of email addresses, as this results in an error, I have been looking into this problem, I know there's probably a very easy fix, but was hoping someone could help!

```
var UserDetails = 
    new UserList
{
UID = x.personid,
Firstname = x.firstname,
Surname = x.surname,
email = x.emailaddress
};
```

**EDIT**

Example of desired output for the email address:

```
dan  
@dan.com
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mention you need to "split _an_ email address (...) across two lines" - what do you want to do with an array of email addresses? Two addresses across four lines?

Comment: You can split an index of that array. Example: string[] str = your array. Str[0].Split("@")

Answer (score 1):

Use linq:

```
  var mails = new[] { "Test@gmail.com", "test@yahoo.com" };

  foreach (var m in mails.Select(x => { var parts = x.Split('@'); return new { Name = parts[0], Host = parts[1] }; }))
  {
     Console.WriteLine(m.Name + "\n@" + m.Host);
  }
```